# `LOCK_EX` prohibits reading, but not writing?

Tags: php, flock

**Why can I not read a file locked with** `LOCK_EX`**?** I am still able to write to it.

I wanted to know, what happens, if one process locks a file (with `LOCK_SH` or `LOCK_EX`) and another process tries to read this file or write to it, but ignores the lock at all. So I made a little script that has 3 functionalities:

- Locking: Opens the target file, writes to it, locks the file (with specified lock), writes to it again, sleeps 10 seconds, unlocks it and closes it.
- Reading: Opens the target file, reads from it and closes it.
- Writing: Opens the target file, writes to it and closes it.

I tested it by having two consoles side by side and doing the folloing:

```
FIRST CONSOLE                |        SECOND CONSOLE
-----------------------------+-----------------------
php test lock LOCK_SH        |        php test read
php test lock LOCK_SH        |        php test write
php test lock LOCK_EX        |        php test read
php test lock LOCK_EX        |        php test write
```

`LOCK_SH` seems to have no effect at all, because the first process as well as the second process can read and write to the file. If the file is being locked with `LOCK_EX` by the first process, both processes can still write to it, but only the first process can read. **Is there any reasoning behind this?**

Here is my little test program (tested on *Windows 7 Home Premium* 64-bit):

```
<?php
    // USAGE: php test [lock | read | write] [LOCK_SH | LOCK_EX]
    // The first argument specifies whether
    //   this script should lock the file, read
    //   from it or write to it.
    // The second argument is only used in lock-mode
    //   and specifies whether LOCK_SH or LOCK_EX
    //   should be used to lock the file


    // Reads $file and logs information.
    function r ($file) {
        echo "Reading file\n";
        if (($buffer = @fread($file, 64)) !== false)
            echo "Read ", strlen($buffer), " bytes: ", $buffer, "\n";
        else
            echo "Could not read file\n";
    }

    // Sets the cursor to 0.
    function resetCursor ($file) {
        echo "Resetting cursor\n", @fseek($file, 0, SEEK_SET) === 0 ? "Reset cursor" : "Could not reset cursor", "\n";
    }

    // Writes $str to $file and logs information.
    function w ($file, $str) {
        echo "Writing \"", $str, "\"\n";
        if (($bytes = @fwrite($file, $str)) !== false)
            echo "Wrote ", $bytes, " bytes\n";
        else
            echo "Could not write to file\n";
    }

    // "ENTRYPOINT"
    if (($file = @fopen("check", "a+")) !== false) {
        echo "Opened file\n";

        switch ($argv[1]) {
        case "lock":
            w($file, "1");

            echo "Locking file\n";
            if (@flock($file, constant($argv[2]))) {
                echo "Locked file\n";

                w($file, "2");
                resetCursor($file);
                r($file);

                echo "Sleeping 10 seconds\n";
                sleep(10);
                echo "Woke up\n";

                echo "Unlocking file\n", @flock($file, LOCK_UN) ? "Unlocked file" : "Could not unlock file", "\n";
            } else {
                echo "Could not lock file\n";
            }

            break;

        case "read":
            resetCursor($file);
            r($file);
            break;

        case "write":
            w($file, "3");
            break;
        }

        echo "Closing file\n", @fclose($file) ? "Closed file" : "Could not close file", "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Could not open file\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very good question, but also a complex one because it depends on a lot of conditions.

We have to start with another pair of locking types - advisory and mandatory:

- Advisory locking simply give you "status flags" by which *you* know if a resource is locked or not.
- Mandatory locking *enforces* the locks, regardless of whether you're checking these "status flags".

... and that should answer your question, but I'll continue in order to explain your particular case.

What you seem to be experiencing is the behavior of advisory locks - there's nothing preventing you from reading or writing to a file, no matter if there is a lock for it or if you even checked for one.
However, you will find a [note in the PHP manual for flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#refsect1-function.flock-notes), saying the following:

> flock() uses mandatory locking instead of advisory locking on Windows. Mandatory locking is also supported on Linux and System V based operating systems via the usual mechanism supported by the fcntl() system call: that is, if the file in question has the setgid permission bit set and the group execution bit cleared. On Linux, the file system will also need to be mounted with the mand option for this to work.

So, if PHP uses mandatory locking on Windows and you've tested this on Windows, either the manual is wrong/outdated/inaccurate (I'm too lazy to check for that right now) **or** you have to read this big red warning on the same page:

> On some operating systems flock() is implemented at the process level. When using a multithreaded server API like ISAPI you may not be able to rely on flock() to protect files against other PHP scripts running in parallel threads of the same server instance!
>
> flock() is not supported on antiquated filesystems like FAT and its derivates and will therefore always return FALSE under this environments (this is especially true for Windows 98 users).

I don't believe it is even possible that your php-cli executable somehow spawns threads for itself, so there's the option that you're using a filesystem that simply doesn't support locking.

My guess is that the manual isn't entirely accurate and you do in fact get *advisory* locks on Windows, because you are also experiencing a different behavior between `LOCK_EX` (exclusive lock) and `LOCK_SH` (shared lock) - it doesn't make sense for them to differ if your filesystem just ignores the locks.

And that brings us to the difference between *exclusive* and *shared* locks or `LOCK_EX` and `LOCK_SH` respectively. The logic behind both is based around *writing*, but there's a slight difference ...

- Exclusive locks are (generally) used when you want to write to a file, because only one process at a time may hold an exclusive lock over the same resource. That gives you safety, because no other process would read from that resource while the lock-holder writes to it.
- Shared locks are used to ensure that a resource is not being written to *while you read from it*. Since no process is writing to the resource, it is not being modified and is therefore safe to read from for multiple processes at the same time.

Comment: I tried checking PHP's source, but at some point there was a call to a function pointer and I gave up. NTFS supports file locking and the native function `LockFileEx` works as you described it, so I think it is implemened on process level. (And +1 for detailed answer :)

Comment: @Narf, When "you may not be able to rely on flock", will flock return true or false? How to detect *that* then?

Comment: @Pacerier Don't know; possibly `true` - that note is about multi-threading, where two separate process threads try to obtain locks on the same resource. Since locking happens at the process level, two threads under the same process ID may both succeed. It is pointless to look at return values under those conditions - if you have such an environment, you simply find a different solution.